# How to pass Codable object in a associatedtype in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have below data from server

```
{ 
  "success": true,
  "terms": "https://currencylayer.com/terms",
  "privacy": "https://currencylayer.com/privacy",
  "timestamp": 1572365346,
  "source": "USD",
  "quotes": {
             "USDBAM": 1.76456,
             "USDTJS": 9.694558,
             "USDYER": 250.349994,
             "USDZAR": 14.592897,
             .......
            }
}
```

Now I have created following to handle above response using `Codable`

```
struct Resource<T: Decodable>: ItemList {

    var quotes: Dictionary<String, Double>
    var success: Bool
    var terms: String
    var privacy: String
    var timestamp: Int
    var source: String
}

protocol ItemList: Decodable {

    associatedtype T: 
    var success: Bool {get}
    var terms: String {get}
    var privacy: String {get}
    var timestamp: Int {get}
    var source: String {get}
    var quotes: T {get}
}
```

Everything works fine but I want 'quotes' as separate model so I created another struct as below

```
struct CurrencyModel: Decodable {
  var quotes: Dictionary<String, Double>
}
```

and mofified 'Resource' as below

```
struct Resource<T: Decodable>: ItemList {
    var quotes: T
    var success: Bool
    var terms: String
    var privacy: String
    var timestamp: Int
    var source: String
}
```

and call

```
CurrencyLayerCommunicator().get(Resource<CurrencyModel>.self) { [weak self] item in
  self?.handleResult(item)
}
```

but this time I am unable to get result & getting decoding error

> Failed to convert into JSON with error: The data couldn’t be read
>   because it is missing.

Please suggest or guide how to fix this issue.

Comment: I'd tend to say that your biggest mistake is to print only `error.localizedDescription` instead of `error`. You'll get much more information. Give it a try, if you don't understand the new message, post the new error log here.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest mistake is to print only `error.localizedDescription` and not `error`.

With this:

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Resource<CurrencyModel>.self, from: jsonData)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print("Localized Description Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    print("Full Error: \(error)")
}
```

You'll have:

```
Localized Description Error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
Full Error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "quotes", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "quotes", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"quotes\", intValue: nil) (\"quotes\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Much more useful.

The issue then, is that you have twice `"quotes"`.

One as a key in `ItemList`, and another one in `CurrencyModel`.

Replace `Resource<CurrencyModel>.self` with `Resource<[String: Double]>.self` and it's working.

In case of JSON Decoding, I also recommend when it's not working in order to debug is to print the reverse version (I replaced `Decodable` by `Codable` in your structs):

```
let currencyModel = CurrencyModel(quotes: ["Currency1": 0.1,
                                           "Currency2": 0.2,
                                           "Currency3": 0.3])
let ressources: Resource<CurrencyModel> = Resource(quotes: currencyModel,
                                                   success: true,
                                                   terms: "terms",
                                                   privacy: "privacy",
                                                   timestamp: 30,
                                                   source: "source")
do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let reversedJSONData = try encoder.encode(ressources)
    if let reversedJSONString = String(data: reversedJSONData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(reversedJSONString)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error in reversing: \(error)")
}
```

This prints

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "quotes" : {
    "quotes" : {
      "Currency1" : 0.10000000000000001,
      "Currency2" : 0.20000000000000001,
      "Currency3" : 0.29999999999999999
    }
  },
  "terms" : "terms",
  "privacy" : "privacy",
  "timestamp" : 30,
  "source" : "source"
}
```

This way you'll see what's supposed to look like your JSON with your current code.

Note that if there is custom init, you'll need to have changes to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON the quotes is a dictionary, you are trying to map that to CurrencyModel. It also expects a key 'quotes' and value as dictionary. In simple way to put what I said, your current implementation expects a JSON like:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "terms":"https://currencylayer.com/terms",
   "privacy":"https://currencylayer.com/privacy",
   "timestamp":1572365346,
   "source":"USD",
   "quotes":{
      "quotes":{
         "USDBAM":1.76456,
         "USDTJS":9.694558,
         "USDYER":250.349994,
         "USDZAR":14.592897
      }
   }
}
```

Instead of creating a struct for CurrencyModel, just use typealias.

```
typealias CurrencyModel = [String: Double]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I think you need one more custom model inside `CurrencyModel` that holds the key/value pairs of the dictionary. Also to make this work `CurrencyModel` needs a custom `init(from:)`

```
struct FxRate {
    let fxPair: String
    let rate: Double
}

struct CurrencyModel: Decodable {
    var fxRates = [FxRate]()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dict = try container.decode([String: Double].self)
        fxRates = dict.map { FxRate(fxPair: $0.key, rate: $0.value)}
    }
}
```